# Referencing Google Classroom SAML Identity Provider

Tags: saml, google-classroom

We're interested in integrating our application with Google Authentication via SAML for online education applications. In this application, we're interested in the following:

- having Google provide authentication/identification of users against a customer's directory (only their directory, not all of google).
- receiving role information that describes the user's role (Teacher, Student, etc.)
- eventually retrieving roster information that describes the relationship of users in the system and their classes.

Our intent is to support Google Classroom customers. I'm looking for a good reference & have open questions after perusing Google's G Suite info. Can you point me to good resources or provide some insight?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the [Classroom API documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/) covers the topics you need (*positive that there's one for managing the roles and rosters, but not so sure with the auth and identification via SAML though*) when wanting to use Google Classroom. This is the place to ask questions about the API. Is there anything unclear in the docs that you would like clarification about?

Comment: There is info in that regard. I've found some references, but nothing conclusive. We're looking at some venues to do a proof of concept, which will help provide empirical data. Wondering if anyone's tried something similar to what we're doing & the corresponding results.  Thanks!